# Selberg Class v/s Modular Forms

Tags: modular-forms

Lately, I started to study Modular Forms, and I had even done some basic study about Selberg Class Functions. But I have not been able to relate the two in any sense.

Another question: Modular Forms are rooted with Elliptic Curves (correspondence with respect to Lattices generating the Elliptic Curves, which motivates us to study Modular Forms). Is there any such a thing for Selberg Class too?

Comment: If $f$ is a newform in $S_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(f) n^{-s-(k-1)/2}$ is in the Selberg class. There is no algebraic object or moduli space canonically associated to any function of the Selberg class, telling when there is such a connexion (and classify and construct them) is the point of the Langlands program (whose starting point is that the Selberg class should be the L-functions of automorphic representations, and many of them correspond to Galois representations).

Comment: The modularity (plus the newform theorem, that $f$ is an eigenfunction of the Fricke involution) implies $\Lambda(s,f) =N^{-s/2} \Gamma(s)\sum a_n(f)n^{-s} =\varepsilon \Lambda(k-s,f)$, then $n^{-(k-1)/2}$ is there to shift the critical line (the symmetry of the functional equation) from $Re(s)=k/2$ to $\Re(s)=1/2$, finally we need the  bound of the Ramanujan conjecture : that $a_p(f)=O(p^{(k-1)/2}$ which comes from the algebraization of the modular curve and the Weil conjectures (the RH for varieties over finite fields).